# MatterMost : How to Fill the Field in LdapSettings?

Tags: configuration, ldap, mattermost

I’m trying to work on **Ldap**---->**LdapSettings**---->**config.json** and I need some clarification about the config ,
This is my config:

```
> “LdapSettings”: { 
  “Enable”: true, 
  “LdapServer”: “myLdapServerAdress”,
  “LdapPort”: 389, 
  “ConnectionSecurity”: “”, 
  “BaseDN”: “dc=XX,dc=com”, // is this true like that ? 
  “BindUsername”: “”, I’m confused about what i should put in this field??
  “BindPassword”: “”, 
  “UserFilter”:“”, 
  “FirstNameAttribute”: “”,
  “LastNameAttribute”: “sn”,
  “EmailAttribute”: “mail”, // i put the @ mail of who??
  “UsernameAttribute”: “uid”, // i don’t have an idea about the uid
  "NicknameAttribute": “”, 
  “IdAttribute”: “uid”,
  “PositionAttribute”: “”, 
  “SyncIntervalMinutes”: 60, 
  “SkipCertificateVerification”: false,
  “QueryTimeout”: 60,
  “MaxPageSize”: 0,
  “LoginFieldName”: “” 
},
```

Thank you for your Help.

Answer (score 1):

First, I suggest that if you haven't already, you take a look at the documentation on configuring LDAP with Mattermost. There is a general introduction [here](https://docs.mattermost.com/deployment/sso-ldap.html), and an explanation of each of the configuration settings [here](https://docs.mattermost.com/administration/config-settings.html#ad-ldap).

Now, on to the specific config file entries for which you've asked for clarification:

**BaseDN**: This is the base distinguished name for your directory, such as `dc=corp,dc=example,dc=com`. If you want to filter the users with access to Mattermost in your LDAP tree, you do that here, so for example if you only want members of the `mattermost` group to have access, you might end up with a value like `ou=mattermost,ou=users,dc=corp,dc=example,dc=com` here.

**BindUsername**: This is the username of a read only account which can bind to the LDAP server, which Mattermost will use to read users from the LDAP server.

**EmailAttribute**: This is the LDAP attribute name which in your LDAP server contains the email address of users. Mattermost will populate the `email` field of each user from this attribute in LDAP.

**UsernameAttribute**: Similar to `EmailAttribute`, Mattermost will use the value of this attribute in each LDAP user to populate the username field in Mattermost. This field value must be unique for every user.